# Setting window.location after downloading a document

Tags: javascript

I have a link to an attachment, and what I'd like to do is redirect the user to a response page when they click on the attachment.

That way the attachment would dl/open and they would automatically be redirected to response.htm.

I've tried capturing it on click and doing a window.location = , but it didn't work.  And when I ran the same function with a link that wasn't to the attachment, it did work.

Comment: You may be missing a `return false;` in your click handler. @raina77ow's example shows how to handle clicks on a link.

Comment: Posting your code would help. You should know with that much rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is opening download request in another window:

```
someLinkElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.open(this.href, 'Download File');
  location.href = someOtherUrl;
  return false;
});
```